# Setting default Save Location in Android 6.0

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, motorola-moto-g2, adoptable-storage

Is there a way to set the default installation from my Apps to SD Card.

I couldn't find it, in `Settings/App/Configurate Apps` and `Setting/Storage & USB`.

Where do i have to look for it?

Thanks

---

My Device is a Moto G (2.Gen) with a 32GB SD Card formatted as `Adoptable Storage` (Marshmallow Feature)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your SD card is setup as adopted (internal) storage, apps should save their information there by default as long as you migrated your apps there, your SD card is now internal storage.

For more information, look at the Moto help page for [Android 6 Marshmallow - SD card - Tips and Tricks](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/109134/p/1449,9582)